# How to search in website and retrieve data using loop

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

Pardon me if my question title is not expressive ,but what I want to say is I have a simple tool that should search in a website and get the result which is 3 kinds of data (name,phone,address) I had written some codes for opening the website inside web browser tool and applied a loop statement to search for 30 numbers and it really works but the problem is it works for only one time and the second problem is in retrieving data from the other page which opens when the search button is clicked ,so suppose that I will start my sequential based number in search as 737000000 it should search for this number and opens the other page which contains the data and put these data in 3 text boxes finally back to previous page and search for 737000001 (adding 1 each time)
My codes are

```
 private void searchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                string temp = string.Format("{0:D6}", i);
                string formula = textBox1.Text + temp;
                        // Get all input elements
                HtmlElementCollection inputs = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
                // Select "txtSearch" input
                HtmlElement input = inputs["q"];
                if (input != null)
                {
                    string value = input.GetAttribute("VALUE");
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                    {
                        // Already searched but no results
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Input search text
                        string searchText = formula;
                        input.SetAttribute("VALUE", searchText);

                        var elements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
                        foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
                        {
                                element.InvokeMember("click");
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
```

the data in the other page when I view the page source appears like

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>number</th>
                    <th>address</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                   <tr>
                        <td><a href="http://yementel.info/737000000">Mat Adam</a></td>
                        <td><a href="tel:737000000"><b class="text-success">737000000</b></a></td>
                        <td>New York</td>
                        </tr>        </tbody>
        </table>
```